# Why i value in for loop didn't go normal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

```
for i in range(2,5):
    for j in range(2,i):
        print(f"i:{i}\tj:{j}")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DieSa.png)

I don't know why the output of i vaule isn't start with 2, anyone could explain this to me?

Comment: A hint: What does `for j in range(2, i)` do when `i = 2`?

Comment: What value of `j` would you expect to be printed when `i` is 2?

Comment: perhaps you are looking for this? `for j in range(2,i+1):`

Answer (score 1):

It's because in the range function, it doesn't include the last number so range(2,2) doesn't do anything because it doesn't include the 2, and for example range(2, 3) would only include the 2 because it wouldn't include the 3.

Answer (score 0):

The value of i starts with 2. It is just that range(2,2) isn’t going to execute.

```
for i in range(2,5):
   for j in range(2,i+1):
      print(f"i:{i}\tj:{j}")
```

Change i into i+1 in the nested loop.

Comment: I would change " isn’t going to execute" to "isn't going to yield anything" because the function does indeed execute.